# Transform pandas DataFrame based on cell information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a pd DataFrame `df` with the following format:

```
model              auc            p             r
`a-num5-run1`      0.9            0.8           1.0
`a-num5-run2`      0.8            0.7           0.9
`b-num5-run1`      0.7            0.6           0.8
`b-num5-run2`      0.6            0.5           0.7
`a-num10-run1`     0.5            0.4           0.6
`a-num10-run2`     0.4            0.3           0.5
`b-num10-run1`     0.3            0.2           0.4
`b-num10-run2`     0.2            0.1           0.3
.... 
`a-num100-run1`     0.8            0.9           0.7
`a-num100-run2`     0.6            0.7           0.4
`a-num100-run1`     0.4            0.5           0.1
`a-num100-run2`     0.2            0.3           0.8
```

The `model` column shows the dimensions in which each model can be distinguished.
Now, I would like to create a DataFrame in which the values per column are averaged over their runs and stored in a tuple, each number is a column and each row is a model (a or b in this case). The desired result would be the matrix as shown below:

```
model_name     5                         10                   ...   100
a              (0.85, 0.75, 0.95)        (0.45, 0.35, 0.55)   ...   (0.7, 0.8, 0.55)
b              (0.65, 0.55, 0.75)        (0.25, 0.15, 0.35)   ...   (0.3, 0.4, 0.45)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First split column to helper `DataFrame` by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), then use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with extract integrers by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with default `mean` and last create tuples:

```
df1 = df['model'].str.split('-', expand=True)

df = (df.pivot_table(index=df1[0], 
                    columns=df1[1].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int), 
                    values=['auc','p','r'], fill_value=0)
       .round(2)
       .T
       .groupby(level=1)
       .agg(tuple)
       .T)
print (df)
1                 5                   10               100
0                                                         
a  (0.85, 0.75, 0.95)  (0.45, 0.35, 0.55)  (0.5, 0.6, 0.5)
b  (0.65, 0.55, 0.75)  (0.25, 0.15, 0.35)  (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

If order of columns is not sorted use:

```
df = df.join(df[['auc','p','r']].add_suffix('_std'))
# print (df)

#not sorted ordering of columns
cols = ['p', 'p_std','auc', 'auc_std', 'r','r_std']

df1 = df['model'].str.split('-', expand=True)

df = (df.pivot_table(index=df1[0], 
                    columns=df1[1].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int), 
                    values=cols, fill_value=0)
       .round(2)
       .reindex(cols, axis=1, level=0)
       .T
       .groupby(level=1)
       .agg(tuple)
       .T)
print (df)
1                                   5                                     10   \
0                                                                               
a  (0.75, 0.75, 0.85, 0.85, 0.95, 0.95)  (0.35, 0.35, 0.45, 0.45, 0.55, 0.55)   
b  (0.55, 0.55, 0.65, 0.65, 0.75, 0.75)  (0.15, 0.15, 0.25, 0.25, 0.35, 0.35)   

1                             100  
0                                  
a  (0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)  
b  (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: When I try to run this with more values, then the order of the variables in the tuples change. On top of the columns from above, I also have the standard deviations associated with each variable. So my variables are: `auc`, `auc_std`, `p`, `p_std`,`r`,`r_std`. However, when I use `values = ['auc', 'auc_std', 'p', 'p_std','r','r_std']` in your code, the order of the variables in the tuples are different. Do you know how I can maintain the same order?

Comment: @Emil - do you think like `values=['p', 'p_std','auc', 'auc_std', 'r','r_std']` ? so if sorted order is different? Answer is edited for this